# Open a file based on the name/dir of the currently opened file

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I would like to either find a vim plugin or write a vimscript function to open
a file in (or under) the same directory as my present file.  The file should 
match one of a list of regex files that is defined in a list.

---

I have a project that looks something like this:

```
src 
     |- controllers
     |  ...
     |- util
     |  ...
     |- widgets
        | - widgetA
        |   | - widgetA.js
        |   | - widgetA.template.html
        | -widgetB
        |   | - widgetB.js
        |   | - widgetB.template.html
        | -widgetC
        |   | - widgetC.js
        |   | - widgetC.template.html
        |   | - someHelpers.js
```

Sample usecase (in the command line):

```
cd src
vim widgets/widgetA/widgetA.js
```

Inside vim:

```
press F4 while in command mode
```

Result:

```
widgetA.template.html is opened in vertical split mode with widgetA.js
```

Template files will either be in one of the following:

- Named the same as the presently opened file but with this regex run on it: `s/js$/tempate.html/`
- Named the same as the presently opened file but with this regex run on it: `s/js$/html/`
- In a subdirectory named templates named as above

I am presently using nerdtree and ctrl-p to speed up file opening, but this is a workflow that 
I use so frequently that I thought it *could* make sense to try to speed it up.  Any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It feels like you are looking for something along the lines of [projectionist](https://github.com/tpope/vim-projectionist) or [fswitch](https://github.com/derekwyatt/vim-fswitch).

#### projectionist

With projectionist you could in theory then just execute `:A`/`:SA` to switch to the alternate file.

So in your `.projections.json` (not tested) file would look something like this:

```
{
  "widgets/*.js": {
    "alternate": "widgets/{}.template.html",
    "type": "widget"
  },
  "widgets/*.template.js": {
    "alternate": "widgets/{}.js",
    "type": "template"
}
```

You can also use `:Ewidget` and `:Etemplate` commands to find a widget/template. These commands will also take fuzzy filenames. e.g. `:Ewidget wta`. You can also open the files in split, vertical splits and tabs via `:Swidget`, `:Vwidget`, and `:Twidget` respectively. Please see `:h projectionist` for more information.

#### fswitch

Another option is to use something like [fswitch](https://github.com/derekwyatt/vim-fswitch) which is a C/C++ .h/.c switcher. Please see `:h fswitch-setup` for more information.

There are a few other plugins that do similar things: [altr](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4202) and [a.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=31) to name a few.

#### vanilla

If plugins are not your thing then you can use `%` tricks. e.g. `:sp %<.template.html`

Or maybe a quick and dirty mapping:

```
nnoremap <f4> %:p:s,\.js$,.X123X,:s,\.template\.html$,\.js,:s,\.X123X$,\.template\.html,<CR>
```

For more information see the following vim wiki page: [Easily switch between source and header file](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Easily_switch_between_source_and_header_file)

#### conclusion

I personally use projectionist and find it meets my needs, especially for navigating a structured project which I find more useful than just a simple switcher like fswitch. Projectionist will also be easier than the vanilla approach to when your needs become wilder.

Comment: Thanks for the awesome answer!  I decided to write my own function to handle this specific usecase, but when that stops working I am defiantly going to install projectionist.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What you want is easy to do in the shell:

```
$ cd src
$ vim -O w*/*A/*
```

but I'm not exactly sure how you see that working in Vim itself. Do you want that to happen in a new tab? Do you want the new pair of files to replace the current pair of files?

Answer (score 0):

Dropping this into the your vimrc and relaunch vim will work.

Presently only working for files ending in `.template.html` that are in the same directory but easy to see how it could work for multiple other cases.  When it can't find the template it opens nerdTree to the current directory.

```
map <F4> :call OpenTemplate()<cr>

function! OpenTemplate()
    " Get the Current directory
    let l:jake = expand('%')

    " Replace .js with .template.html
    let l:jake = substitute(l:jake, ".js$", ".template.html", "")

    " Verify that the file exists and it it does open in using vs (see :help vs)
    " if the file can't be found, open nerdTree
    if filereadable(l:jake)
        execute 'vs ' . l:jake
    else
        echo 'Cant find template'
        :NERDTreeFind
    endif

endfunction
```